# Clojure style function "threading" in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming, clojure

Clojure has a "->" macro which inserts each expression recursively as the first argument of the next expression.

This means that I could write:

```
(-> arg f1 f2 f3)
```

and it behaves like (shell piping):

```
f3(f2(f1(arg)))
```

I would like to do this in Python; however, searching seems to be a nightmare!  I couldn't search for "->", and neither could I search for Python function *threading*!

Is there a way to overload, say, the | operator so that I could write this in Python?

```
arg | f1 | f2 | f3
```

Thanks!

Comment: dependig on how crazy you want to get, it might be worth checking out python `hy`  at https://github.com/hylang/hy .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can easily implement something like this yourself.

```
def compose(current_value, *args):
    for func in args:
        current_value = func(current_value)
    return current_value

def double(n):
    return 2*n

print compose(5, double, double) # prints 20
```

Answer (score 23):

Or possibly use the reduce function in the following way:

```
reduce(lambda x,f : f(x), [f1,f2,f3], arg)
```

Comment: This is a very clean and functional way of implementing it.  Thanks!  The other ways that are presented do the same as well, but "arg" is in front and I think that makes a lot of difference in terms of the flow of writing code.

Comment: @Vimal: If you are concerned about ordering you may use reduce(lambda x,f : f(x), [arg,f1,f2,f3]).

Answer (score 10):

Or try https://mdk.fr/blog/pipe-infix-syntax-for-python.html
A module that provide a syntax like :

```
  fib() | take_while(lambda x: x < 1000000)
        | where(lambda x: x % 2)
        | select(lambda x: x * x)
        | sum()
```

Answer (score 8):

Building on Howard's solution:

```
def T(*args):
  return reduce(lambda l, r: r(l), args)

def dbl(n):
    return 2*n

T(5,dbl,dbl)
#=> 20

T(5,dbl,dbl,lambda x: 3*x)
#=> 60
```

Answer (score 3):

While I sympathize with the desire to create cool new language constructs (à la Lisp macros), it is not really the Python philosophy to do this:

```
>>> import this
[...]
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
```

But as the respondents have said, you can do your function chaining in a variety of ways.  Here is one that's perhaps more explicitly Lisp-like, if that suits your fancy:

```
a = lambda x: x*2
b = lambda x: x+1

def chain(first, *args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        return first
    else:
        return first(chain(*args))

print chain(b, a, 1)
```

Comment: Python's lisp influences are what makes it great.

Comment: The appropriateness of Lisp in Python depends on the project in question.  The demographics of the potential developer community weigh strongly here.  Writing a parsing library? Lispiness for the win!  Doing numerics? Use Lisp and lose 90% of your developer pool.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party, but here's a cleaner method, imo. Will suit most FP needs.

```
def stream(*args):
    return reduce(lambda a, t: t[0](t[1], a), args[1:], args[0])
```

A basic map, filter, reduce:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> stream(my_list, 
...    (map,    lambda x: x ** 2),
...    (filter, lambda x: x < 20),
...    (reduce, lambda a, x: a + x))
30
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a [thread function](http://toolz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.thread_last) in the pytoolz library (actually there are two; they do slightly different things on functions of multiple arguments).

There's also a cython implementation of the pytoolz library called [cytoolz](https://github.com/pytoolz/cytoolz/tree/master/cytoolz) which is probably more efficient. It can be installed using `pip`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a quite "Pythonic" approach to this would be to thread functions like this:

```
thread_functions(my_arg)(func1, func2, ...)
```

Or, if you have multiple initial arguments:

```
thread_functions(arg1, arg2, ...)(func1, func2, ...)
```

To implement the above, one could do:

```
def thread_functions(*init_args):
    def execute_functions(*functions_list):
        x = functions_list[0](*init_args)

        for func in functions_list[1:]:
            try:
                x = func(*x)
            except TypeError:
                x = func(x)

        return x

return execute_functions
```

The function `thread_functions` receives the initial set of arguments (that can be many) and returns the function `execute_functions`. When called, `execute_functions` receives a set of functions to iterate on, appling the result of the previous iteration as the arguments to the current function. It also handles both iterable and non iterable arguments.

In [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/EEmery/f48229b3d05754a34f95c130e1e0f157) I left some other explanations and implemented some examples to better demonstrate the use cases.

Answer (score -3):

No, there is not (at least sanely). Nor would you want to. Why not just write `f3(f2(f1(arg)))`? Or better yet, model your problem in a way that doesn't require recursion.

You might be able to overload `|` by wrapping expressions in a class and defining `__or__` in that class, but please, for the love of Guido, don't do that.

You could also do what `btilly` wrote, but I wouldn't recommend that either. Work within what the language provides you.

Comment: huh, why do you mention recursion out of the blue?

Comment: @Jochen `->` in Clojure is recursive in nature

Comment: I know that Guido doesn't like functional techniques, but that is no reason to not tell people who like them how to use them in Python.

Comment: Readability is a matter of taste and specific circumstance.  For instance the Schwartzian transform is more understandable followed left to right, top to bottom.  As for performance, it if is a major concern of yours, then you shouldn't use Python at all.

Comment: @JochenRitzel, in Clojure, `->` is not 'recursive in nature'.